# Apple Server: "Trust this computer" automatically via Profile manager

Tags: ios, apple-ios, mdm

I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to push a "Trusted computers" list to an iOS-device via Profile manager. This to avoid the annoying "Trust this computer?"-dialog when connecting to a computer in this list.

So is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: When you say "Connecting to to a computer" what protocols are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there seems no such possiblity.

In the official apple profile manager help site you can have a look at the list of settings available to configure with Profile manager. They are listed under **Configuration profile reference** in various categories. As far as I can see, there is no such option available.

The full list can be seen here:

https://help.apple.com/profilemanager/mac/4.2/?lang=en

As for the "Trust this Computer" message, here is what Apple says: [‘Trust This Computer‘ alert on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202778)

According to that article:

> If you tap Trust, the computer will be trusted until you untrust all
>   computers or you erase the device. If you tap Don't Trust, you'll see
>   this alert each time you connect your device to that computer.